# using random_split() in python to split the Trainset to train and validation

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

```
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(data_dir, train=True, download=True)
test_dataset  = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(data_dir, train=False, download=True)
```

using two above lines I load the Mnist dataset and then transfered them to Tensor and Dataloader using below lines of code

```
tr =transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),])
train_dataset.transform = tr
test_dataset.transform = tr
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=256, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=256, shuffle=False)
```

and then by using the for loop such as bellow I iterate over the data and do training model in pytorch.

```
for i in train_dataloader:
```

But when I split the training data into two parts using random_split I get error using the **for loop**

```
train_dataset, val_dataset = random_split(train_dataset, (50000, 10000))

train_dataset.transform = tr
test_dataset.transform = tr
val_dataset.transform = tr

train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=256, shuffle=True)
validation_dataloader = DataLoader(val_dataset, batch_size=256, shuffle=True)
test_dataloader = DataLoader(test_dataset, batch_size=256, shuffle=False)
```

The error is:

```
default_collate: batch must contain tensors, numpy arrays, numbers, dicts or lists; found <class 'PIL.Image.Image'>
```

How can solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass `transform` to your `FashionMNIST` dataset's constructor directly.

```
train_dataset = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(data_dir, train=True, download=True, transform=tr)
test_dataset  = torchvision.datasets.FashionMNIST(data_dir, train=False, download=True, transform=tr)
```